# Problem with round() when turning a list into an array

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures, rounding

I created a list with an element being rounded:

```
In [1] list = [(0.382, 0.618, round(411.8724133605957,2))]
       list
```

Well, it's fine as a `list`:

```
Out [1] [(0.382, 0.618, 411.87)]
```

but when I turned it into an array using `np.array()`, all the decimals just popped up again:

```
In [2] array = np.array(list)
       array

Out [2] array([[3.8200e-01, 6.1800e-01, 4.1187e+02]])
```

I then tried `np.round()` and `np.around()` to that array but nothing happened:

```
In [3] np.round(array,2), np.around(array,2)

Out [3] (array([[3.8000e-01, 6.2000e-01, 4.1187e+02]]),
         array([[3.8000e-01, 6.2000e-01, 4.1187e+02]]))
```

Very interesting though, but I don't understand why, and how can I get an array like below:

```
array[[0.382, 0.618, 411.87]]
```

Any idea is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It's just how the numbers are represented. `4.1187e+02` and `411.87` are the same number printed in different forms. To force the latter, try `np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just the way numpy represents these decimals, the values are the same.

If you want it to display regularly, try [`np.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Before your code, maybe a line below you `numpy` import, add this line of code:

```
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

Then printing `array` would look like this:

```
[[   0.382    0.618  411.87 ]]
```